# How can I create HTTP API Key based authentication in laravel passport

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I learnt, Passport allows to authenticate API using OAuth2. But I needed solution to use API-Key in Passport to authenticate.

Can anyone provide any resource and information how could I achieve solution?

Comment: [Questions like yours are considered off-topic on this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please do some digging yourself; there is plenty of material out there. If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it here. If you already have some code, you can add this too

Comment: agree with @rollstuhlfahrer .. this is what i got from a direct search in google and laravel website:
[passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport)
and
[laravel code](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-passport-create-rest-api-with-authentication)